# vba regular expressions - second string match optional

Tags: regex, vba

this must be easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer. I have below reg expression:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "reminder[s]?\s{0,3}?to?\s{0,3}?"
```

I want to match "reminder" with possible word "to". I can't make it work so that it matches "reminder to" and "reminder". Am I using statement "to?" in a wrong way? I hope to achieve:

"reminders  to  customer" - returns "reminders  to  "

"reminder customer" - returns "reminder "

thank you

Edit: Based on answer below, adjusted to suitable solution:

```
(reminder[s]?(?:\s+to)?)(\s+)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(reminder(?:s?\s+to)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/tP7vP9/4

It will match `reminder`, `reminder to`, `reminders to`.

Comment: thank you so much. Makes me jealous how some can answer in 5 min what I have been testing for an hour :). If it's not too much to ask, can you tell me logic of the part right after bracket starts: "?:s"

Comment: No problem. Just takes practice. ?: means non capturing group. So match it but don't capture.